# Qt & OpenGLWindow - flicker on resizing

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

[image]

It appears if I drag-resize fast enough, the window itself is created by subclassing qwindow and making an openGLcontext on it

Code:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QOpenGLContext>
#include <QWindow>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core>
#include <stdio.h>

class OpenGLWindow : public QWindow, protected QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core{

     public:
     explicit OpenGLWindow();
     ~OpenGLWindow();
     virtual void render();
     bool isWindowInitialized;
     void exposeEvent(QExposeEvent *event);
     bool event(QEvent *event);

     private:
     QOpenGLContext* ctx;
     QSurfaceFormat* fmt;
     bool isGLInitialized;
     GLuint VertexArrayID;
     GLuint buffer1;
     GLuint ProgramID;
};

bool OpenGLWindow::event(QEvent *event)
{
     switch (event->type()) {
     case QEvent::UpdateRequest:
     render();
     return true;
     case QEvent::Close:
     glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
     glDeleteBuffers(1, &buffer1);
     glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
     glDeleteProgram(ProgramID);
     return QWindow::event(event);
     case QEvent::Resize:
     if(isWindowInitialized && isGLInitialized)glViewport(0,0,width(),height());
     return QWindow::event(event);
     default:
     return QWindow::event(event);
     }
}

void OpenGLWindow::exposeEvent(QExposeEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);
    if (isExposed())render();
}

OpenGLWindow::OpenGLWindow()
    :ctx(new QOpenGLContext)
    ,fmt(new QSurfaceFormat)
    ,isGLInitialized(0)
{
     setSurfaceType(OpenGLSurface);
     fmt->setRenderableType(QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);
     fmt->setVersion(3,3);
     resize(640,480);
     fmt->setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
     setFormat(*fmt);
     ctx->setFormat(*fmt);
     ctx->create();
}

OpenGLWindow::~OpenGLWindow()
{}

void OpenGLWindow::render(){

 //if(Image::isWindowInitialized || isExposed())return;

 if(!isGLInitialized){

         ctx->makeCurrent(this);
         initializeOpenGLFunctions();

         GLuint vsID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
         GLuint fsID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

         const char* vs="#version 330 core\n layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace; \n void main(){ gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace; gl_Position.w = 1.0;}";

         const char* fs="#version 330 core\n out vec4 color;\n void main(){ color = vec4(1,0,0,1);}";

         glShaderSource(vsID, 1, &vs , NULL);
         glCompileShader(vsID);
         GLint isCompiled = 0;
         glGetShaderiv(vsID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isCompiled);

         if(isCompiled == GL_FALSE){
         GLint maxLength = 0;
         glGetShaderiv(vsID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);
         char info[512];
         glGetShaderInfoLog(vsID, maxLength, &maxLength, info);
         printf("%s",info);}

        glShaderSource(fsID, 1, &fs , NULL);
         glCompileShader(fsID);
         glGetShaderiv(fsID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isCompiled);

        if(isCompiled == GL_FALSE){
         GLint maxLength = 0;
         glGetShaderiv(fsID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);
         char info[512];
         glGetShaderInfoLog(fsID, maxLength, &maxLength, info);
         printf("%s",info);
        }

        GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
         glAttachShader(ProgramID, vsID);
         glAttachShader(ProgramID, fsID);
         glLinkProgram(ProgramID);
         glDeleteShader(vsID);
         glDeleteShader(fsID);

        static const GLfloat data1[] = { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };


        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
        glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
        glGenBuffers(1, &buffer1);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,buffer1);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data1),data1, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0 ,3 ,GL_FLOAT ,GL_FALSE,0 ,(void*)0 );
        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f,1.0f);
        glUseProgram(ProgramID);
        glViewport(0,0,width(),height());
        isGLInitialized=true;
    }

     if(isExposed()){
     glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
     glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
     ctx->swapBuffers(this);
     }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
     OpenGLWindow* win = new OpenGLWindow();
     win->show();
     win->isWindowInitialized=true;
     return app.exec();
}
```

I'm using Qt 5.4.2 on Qt Creator 3.4.1
Kit : Desktop Qt 5.4.2 MSVC2013 64bit

I'm kida lost here since i've never used openGL in qt and it's hard for me to picture where the problem might originate

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a combination of any of the following attributes:

```
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent, true);
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen, true);
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DontCreateNativeAncestors, true);
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NativeWindow, true);
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground, true);
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_MSWindowsUseDirect3D, true);
this->setAutoFillBackground(false);
```