# QGraphicsView flickers on resizing, probably on a lower OpenGL mode

Tags: qt, opengl-es-2.0

I have a QGraphicsView occupying a central role in an application, with thousands of items in it.

I deploy it to a wide variety of platforms, including PC (both Windows and Linux), Android and Raspberry Pi 2. It works on all of them, although scrolling and zooming is very slow and laggy on the Raspberry Pi 2.

Therefore I decided to try an OpenGL viewport:

```
QOpenGLWidget *opengl = new QOpenGLWidget;
ui->graphicsView->setViewport(opengl);
```

(the old QGLWidget doesn't work on the RPi as the RPi uses EGLFS which only supports one native window. QOpenGLWidget uses a framebuffer instead of creating a new native window)

This works well on all platforms, scrolling and zooming is very smooth even on the RPi.

However, there is a problem. Whenever I resize the QGraphicsView, it flickers with a temporary black screen. I need the resizing, as I often open side panels which have to then shrink the QGraphicsView instead of hiding parts of it.

I tried the following, without success:

- the settings in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37639850/788824).
- turning off AutoFillBackground
- specifying a depthBufferSize in its QSurfaceFormat. Curiously, it started with 0, I set it successfully to 24.
- I cannot change swapBehavior for the QSurfaceFormat. It stays at 0 no matter what I try to set it to. Strange, as the renderer uses OpenGL-es-2.0 which should support double buffering. Nevertheless, the view is very fast and responsive, and exchanging large pixmaps with other images is also fast and smooth.
- Increasing the memory size allocated to the GPU in raspi-config.
- Decreasing the size of the QGraphicsView, and drastically reducing the number of elements in it (to make sure it fits into memory several times over)
- trying all combinations in setViewportUpdateMode() and setTransformationAnchor()
- temporarily setting a QWidget as the viewport, resizing, then setting the viewport back to QOpenGLWidget again. The flickering occurs when I set the viewport from QOpenGLWidget to QWidget.
- suggestion by Kuba Ober: putting the QGraphicsView inside of a QOpenGLWidget.

However, the problem should be within the QGraphicsView or some of its settings, not in the RPi or its graphics driver alone (this is why I'm asking here, not on the [raspberry](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) site). I have the following proofs:

- If I create a separate QOpenGLWidget and write some OpenGL code for it, it works fine and resizes without flickering. If I change the [hellogl2](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-hellogl2-example.html) example so that the QOpenGLWidget is resized with the button presses, it is resizing fine without any artifacts.
- Interestingly, if I put my QGraphicsView into a QSplitter and move the splitter manually, the flickering does not occur. However, if I move the splitter with setSizes(), it does flicker! So long for an easy trick! If I move the splitter manually, no matter how fast and by how much, the flickering does not occur, but the height or width properties of the view do change (so it's not because it is just moved off-screen). When I try to move the splitter from the software, if its position is just one pixel away from the position I set it to, the view flickers.

My workaround would be to not resize the QGraphicsView when I open or resize a sidebar, the sidebar would be overlaying the QGraphicsView and I change the boundingRect of the QGraphicsScene to push the visible part out from behind the sidebar. I checked and it works without flickering. However, I think this is an ugly hack, and the real problem would remain unresolved, potentially causing other trouble in the future.

Comment: A similar, but unrelated (and solved) problem: http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-61820.html

Comment: Try using `QOpenGLWidget` as the top-level window in your application, and using regular widgets everywhere else as children.

Comment: @KubaOber : The top-level window is a QMainWindow, but I created a `QOpenGLWidget` inside it, added a layout to it, and inside this I placed a `QGraphicsView` with its viewport set to a new `QOpenGLWidget`.  It still flickers when I resize it. It doesn't matter if I resize the `QOpenGLWidget` which contains the `QGraphicsView` or the `QGraphicsView` itself, the view flickers in both cases.

Comment: Try getting the `QOpenGLWidget` as the topmost window, and then put a `QMainWindow` and everything else inside of it.

Comment: @KubaOber : I tried, the same flickering still happens. `MainWindow w; QOpenGLWidget glwidget; QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(&glwidget); layout->addWidget(&w); glwidget.show();` instead of the old `MainWindow w; w.show();`